ASP.NET Core Identity interferes with StatusCodePages 404 middleware
I'm using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages 7 with Identity. Suppose I navigate to:
/non-existent-page

I expect it to show the 404 page, but it actually redirects to the login page and shows:
/login/?return=%2Fnon-existent-page

After I login, it will redirect to the 404 page.
My config:

The startup config includes this:
services.AddAuthorization(x => {
  x.FallbackPolicy = x.DefaultPolicy;
});


The status code middleware is placed before other middleware:
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error", "?statusCode={0}")


Middleware order: exception handler, status code, static files, routing, authn, authz, razor pages, controllers
The error page has [AllowAnonymous]
The error PageModel class has public void OnGet(int statusCode) { }

How do I fix this?

Intuition says that routing middleware is placed after authentication/authorization middleware, but should be before it.

@Ryan Thanks. Agreed, I have it that way already. My middlware order: exception handler, status code, static files, routing, authn, authz, razor pages, controllers.

Static files should be before status code also. For example, if some css/image is absent status code will reexecute the whole pipleline just for that simple css in order to fill up response body. It creates some overhead for CPU usage and might impact a lot if your web application is quite highloaded. Placing static before status codes will return just status code with empty body.

I found a solution on this page in the docs; however, that code is incorrect:
public class SampleAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler defaultHandler = new();

    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        // If the authorization was forbidden and the resource had a specific requirement,
        // provide a custom 404 response.
        if (authorizeResult.Forbidden
            && authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure!.FailedRequirements
                .OfType<Show404Requirement>().Any())
        {
            // Return a 404 to make it appear as if the resource doesn't exist.
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return;
        }

        // Fall back to the default implementation.
        await defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
    }
}

public class Show404Requirement : IAuthorizationRequirement { }

This modified code works:
public class NotFoundAwareAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler _defaultHandler = new();

    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        if (!authorizeResult.Succeeded &&
            authorizeResult.Challenged &&
            context.GetEndpoint() == null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
            return;
        }
        await _defaultHandler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
    }

}

Despite it working for me, I'm unsure whether it is appropriate in all scenarios:

the original code checks authorizeResult.Forbidden which is pointless in this case, but perhaps one should use authorizeResult.Challenged || authorizeResult.Forbidden
it also checks authorizeResult.AuthorizationFailure!.FailedRequirements but that is always null
my code checks context.GetEndpoint() == null, which is the case for a non-existent page, whereas it would be non-null for an existing page; I hope there are no gotchas there

I added an issue to the docs repo asking for them to fix it. Please upvote that if you also need it.
And if you have a better approach, or spot an error in my code, please add an answer and I'll accept it.
